# How do I setup Sendmail + Dovecot + Roundcube on CentOS6

Tags: centos6, dovecot, roundcube, postfix

Pretty much what the title says. I've been digging all over the internet trying to figure this stuff out.

I have a CentOS 6 box. I have Sendmail and Dovecot and Roundcube all installed. Roundcube can't send mail out because Sendmail doesn't have some auth plugin. I've tried installing the auth plugin and sendmail still doesn't use it.

I seriously just don't understand email setup. Its a total pain. I also need SSL support, I don't even know where to begin. The only answer I've been given is "Read the manual". Well, that doesn't help, its huge and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and did Postfix + postfix.admin + Dovecot + Roundcube and the setup was very easy. I used this tutorial

http://www.campworld.net/thewiki/pmwiki.php/LinuxServersCentOS/Cent6VirtMailServer

I used parts from this tutorial to setup pipes

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Configuring_Postfix_to_work_with_piped_scripts

Mainly this part.. (Edited since we are not using Zimbra)

**Edit /etc/postfix/transport and place the following lines at the top**

```
# Pipe transports for RT queues
# YOU HAVE TO ADD THE PIPES TO /etc/postfix/master.cf if you want them to work!!!
rt@example.com     rt-pipe
rt-comment@example.com     rt-comment-pipe
```

**Create the transport db by executing**

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

**The transport definitions 'rt-pipe' and 'rt-comment-pipe' must now be defined. Edit /etc/postfix/master.cf.in and add the following lines to the end of the file**

```
rt-pipe         unix    -       n               n               -               -       pipe
    flags= user=www argv=/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/php/script.php
rt-comment-pipe         unix    -       n               n               -               -       pipe
    flags= user=www argv=/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/php/script.php
```

*To make it all work, I had to create an alias for rt@example.com back to its self rt@example.com in postfix.admin, otherwise I was presented with this error..
550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
 This part will probably differ depending on the setup you have used*

**Restart postfix and test**

```
service postfix restart
```

I decided the setup I was going for just could not be accomplished, so I'm hosting email in two spots. It isn't a huge deal though, everything is working fine for me now. DNS is helping point where the email is hosted, and we have no issues with this setup what so ever.

Also should note that mxtoolbox reports it is not an open relay, and all is configured nicely. This is actually the preferred setup for what we are going to be doing with our servers anyway, so I've added all the steps to an auto configuration script for new servers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use postfix instead of sendmail. It's a little bit easier to understand. Take a look at the Centos [wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix) there is an article on how to setup a simple mail server.

Also please check out the [workaround](https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/big-picture) tutorial it explains step by step what needs to be done (and most important why) it is designed for Debian but it's really easy to modify it for CentOS. In case you're still not confident, find someone who could do the setup for you. There is a chance that you will do something wrong and create an open relay which will be exploited by spamers.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this. I did end up with postfix instead of sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

I would get postfix + dovecot working, and worry about roundcube after. You only need a web server (and database) for Roundcube.

This one is for Centos 5, but should be close.

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

Comment: I wish I could upvote this also, I did end up using postfix and dovecot. I also used postfix.admin, but will be replacing that with a panel we write ourselves. Not saying postfix.admin isn't good, it is just fine, but we will be using our own branded solution.